# Why doesn't JQuery hover animate work in this example

Tags: jquery

When I hover over the box it doesn't change it's caller as I intent. What's wrong?

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<style type="text/css" >
.box_type1{
    width:560px;
    height:560px;

    background-color:#b0c4de;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.box_type1').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#4E1402'}, 300);
        }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#943D20'}, 100);
    });

    });
</script>
<body>

</div>

    <div class="box_type1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, [you can see here for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmLcj/).

You'll need either the [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) for [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this though (to animate most non-numeric properties), for example using UI from the CDN (if you have other uses for UI...use the color plugin if this animation is all you're after, much smaller):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also there's an extra `</div>` in your `<body>`, make sure to remove it, invalid HTML causes all sorts of unpredictable behavior, especially cross-browser :)

Comment: You added jQuery UI in that demo, which isn't included in the original code.

Comment: @Coronatus - Woops use that setup as a template, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't do background color animations with a plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Also, your HTML is quite invalid so that might still cause a failure.

More valid:

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css" >
        .box_type1{
            width:560px;
            height:560px;
            background-color:#b0c4de;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.box_type1').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#4E1402'}, 300);
                }, function () {
                $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#943D20'}, 100);
            });

            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box_type1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```